# CheckBox, ListView and BaseAdapter: CheckBox can't be unchecked

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to code a `BaseAdapter` with a `CheckBox` that will enable to select/unselect several items. When an item is selected/unselected, I want to perform a specific action.

I am using an `OnCheckedChangedListener` because I could not make the `OnItemClickListener` work (the `OnItemClick()` method was never called). Now I can see the `onCheckedChanged()` method called on my logcat but I can't uncheck an *Item* and even if I click on an item several times, the method `onCheckedChanged()` is called only once.

Please note that this code I use to add a new menu (row) in the Settings menu of the Android system (may be this introduces some limitations that I am not aware of).
Here is my code:

File nfc_routing_overflow_option.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/nfc_routing_overflow"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="24dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOther"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:checked="false"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerOther"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
            />
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOther"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

File nfc_routing_overflow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/*
* Copyright 2012, The Android Open Source Project
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/overflow_list"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

File NfcRoutingOverflow.java:

```
package com.android.settings.nfc;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.android.internal.logging.MetricsLogger;
import com.android.settings.R;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.settings.SettingsPreferenceFragment;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.cardemulation.ApduServiceInfo;
import android.nfc.cardemulation.CardEmulation;
import android.nfc.cardemulation.AidGroup;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class NfcRoutingOverflow extends SettingsPreferenceFragment{

    public static final String TAG = "SETTINGSNfcRoutingOverflow";
    static final boolean DBG = true;

    private  NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private  CardEmulation mCardEmuManager;
    private  Context mContext;
    private  LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private  NfcOverflowAdapter mOverflowAdapter;
    private  ListView mListView;

    class NfcOtherOverflow
    {
        CharSequence label;
        CharSequence description;
        Drawable banner;
        public ComponentName componentName;
        public AidGroup aidGroup;
        public int uid;
        boolean selected = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getMetricsCategory() {
        return MetricsLogger.NFC_PAYMENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()" );

        mContext = getActivity();

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(mContext);
        mCardEmuManager = CardEmulation.getInstance(mAdapter);
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mOverflowAdapter = new NfcOverflowAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated()" );

        ViewGroup contentRoot = (ViewGroup) getListView().getParent();

        View emptyView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nfc_routing_overflow, contentRoot, false);

        contentRoot.addView(emptyView);

        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
        List<ApduServiceInfo> serviceInfos =
                mCardEmuManager.getServices(CardEmulation.CATEGORY_OTHER);

        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated() - Nb of services in category OTHER found: " + serviceInfos.size());


        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow_list);

        ArrayList<NfcOtherOverflow> appList = new ArrayList<NfcOtherOverflow>();

        for(ApduServiceInfo service:serviceInfos)
        {
            NfcOtherOverflow appOther = new NfcOtherOverflow();
            ArrayList<AidGroup> aidGroups = service.getAidGroups();

            if (DBG)
                Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated() - Processing service:  " + service.getDescription() + ", with " + aidGroups.size() + " AidGroup");

            if(aidGroups.size() > 0)
            {
                for(AidGroup aidGroup : aidGroups)
                {
                    appOther.label = service.loadLabel(pm);
                    if (appOther.label == null)
                    {
                        appOther.label = service.loadAppLabel(pm);
                    }

                    appOther.componentName = service.getComponent();

                    appOther.description = service.getDescription();

                    appOther.banner = service.loadBanner(pm);
                    appOther.aidGroup = aidGroup;
                    appOther.uid = service.getUid();
                    appList.add(appOther);
                }
            }
        }

        if (appList.size() != 0)
        {
            NfcOtherOverflow[] apps = appList.toArray(new NfcOtherOverflow[appList.size()]);
            mOverflowAdapter.updateApps(apps, null);
        }

        mListView.setAdapter(mOverflowAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu()" );

    }

    class NfcOverflowAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

        // Only modified on UI thread
        private NfcOtherOverflow[] appInfos;

        public NfcOverflowAdapter() {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - constructor" );
        }

        public void updateApps(NfcOtherOverflow[] appInfos, NfcOtherOverflow currentDefault) {

            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - updateApps() - Nb apps: " + appInfos.length);

            // Clone app infos, only add those with a banner
            this.appInfos = appInfos;

       //     notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - getCount()" );
            return appInfos.length;
        }

        @Override
        public NfcOtherOverflow getItem(int i) {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - getItem()" );
            return appInfos[i];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - getItemId()" );
            return appInfos[i].componentName.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - getView() - position: " + position);

            final ViewHolder holder;
            NfcOtherOverflow appInfo = appInfos[position];

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nfc_routing_overflow_option, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bannerOther);
                holder.radioButton = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOther);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textOther);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.radioButton.setContentDescription(appInfo.label);
            holder.radioButton.setTag(appInfo);
            holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            if(appInfo.banner != null)
            {
                holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(appInfo.banner);
            }
            else
            {
                Drawable dummy = mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_settings_nfc_payment);
                holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(dummy);
            }

            holder.imageView.setTag(appInfo);
            holder.imageView.setContentDescription(appInfo.label);

            holder.textView.setContentDescription(appInfo.label);
            holder.textView.setText(appInfo.aidGroup.getDescription());

            AidGroup aidGroup = appInfo.aidGroup;
            boolean isEnabled = aidGroup.isGroupEnabled();
            if(isEnabled == true)
            {
                holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - onCheckedChanged() - isChecked: " + isChecked);

            NfcOtherOverflow appInfo = (NfcOtherOverflow) buttonView.getTag();

            AidGroup aidGroup = appInfo.aidGroup;

            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - onClick() - AidGroup description: " + aidGroup.getDescription());

            aidGroup.setIsEnabled(isChecked);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        public class ViewHolder {
            public CheckBox radioButton;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public TextView textView;
        }


        public void updateRouting(View view)
        {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - updateRouting()" );

            NfcOtherOverflow appInfo = (NfcOtherOverflow) view.getTag();

            AidGroup aidGroup = appInfo.aidGroup;

            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - onCheckedChanged() - AidGroup description: " + aidGroup.getDescription());

            boolean isEnabled = true;

            if(((CheckBox)view).isChecked() == false)
            {
                isEnabled = false;
            }

            aidGroup.setIsEnabled(isEnabled);

            //Inform system of changes
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_UID, appInfo.uid);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CHANGED_COMPONENT_NAME_LIST, appInfo.componentName);
            mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

//            /notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}
```

Could someone please help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

NOTE: The method `updateRouting()` of the `NfcOverflow` class is not used for now.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting your checkbox inside onCheckChanged?. Add radioButton.setChecked(false/true); inside onCheckChanged.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. You mean I should call the setChecked() inside the onCheckedChanged() method right?

Comment: But my problem is, on the display, the Item I click on is already checked. When a click on it, it won't uncheck and on my log I have the following: '02-02 23:55:16.677  1325  1325 D SETTINGSNfcRoutingOverflow: NfcOverflowAdapter - onCheckedChanged() - isChecked: true'  which means the system has only registered that I touched the item, it has not detected that I tried to unchecked the CheckBox.

Comment: if (isChecked) { radioButton.setChecked(false);} else { radioButton.setChecked(true);}. Add this inside onCheckChanged

Comment: My problem is that every time I try to uncheck a CheckBox by touching the screen, it won't uncheck and onCheckedChanged() is always called with isChecked = true.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get `NfcOtherOverflow` using `buttonView.getTag()`

Try getting `NfcOtherOverflow` from `appInfos` using index/position e.g. `appInfos[position]`

```
holder.radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - onCheckedChanged() - isChecked: " + isChecked);

        NfcOtherOverflow appInfo = appInfos[position];;

        AidGroup aidGroup = appInfo.aidGroup;

        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "NfcOverflowAdapter - onClick() - AidGroup description: " + aidGroup.getDescription());

        aidGroup.setIsEnabled(isChecked);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I tried your method but it doesn't make any change: I can't uncheck my CheckBox when touching the screen, and onCheckedChanged() is always called only once (even if I touch the item on the screen several times) with isChecked = true.